# Checksum result destination overlaps with checksum range

Tags: bootloader, microchip, dspic, xc16

I'm trying to configure a project with [Microchip 16-bit Bootloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFxU3.png). The target MCU is [dsPIC33CK512MP608](https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/Calculating-and-storing-checksum). Ubuntu 22.10, MPLAB X IDE v6.05, latest versions of MCC and all the libraries.

Here the memory configuration:

[image]

I added the macro to be executed after build:

```
cd mcc_generated_files/boot && ./postBuild.sh $(MP_CC_DIR) ${ProjectDir} ${ImageDir} ${ImageName} ${IsDebug}
```

Here the contents of the macro:

```
if [ "$5" = "true" ]; then
exit 0
fi
hexmate r0-4FFF,"$2/$3/$4" r5008-FFFFFFFF,"$2/$3/$4" -O"$2/$3/temp_original_copy.X.production.hex" -FILL=w1:0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00@0x5000:0x5007
hexmate r5000-FFFFFFFF,"$2/$3/temp_original_copy.X.production.hex" -O"$2/$3/temp_crc.X.production.hex" -FILL=w1:0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x00@0x5000:0xAEFFF +-CK=5000-AEFFF@5000w-4g5p814141AB
hexmate r5000-5001,"$2/$3/temp_crc.X.production.hex" r5002-FFFFFFFF,"$2/$3/$4" r0-4FFF,"$2/$3/$4" -O"$2/$3/$4"
hexmate r5000-FFFFFFFF,"$2/$3/temp_original_copy.X.production.hex" -O"$2/$3/temp_crc.X.production.hex" -FILL=w1:0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x00@0x5000:0xAEFFF +-CK=5000-AEFFF@5002w-4g5p814141AB
hexmate r5004-5005,"$2/$3/temp_crc.X.production.hex" r5006-FFFFFFFF,"$2/$3/$4" r0-5003,"$2/$3/$4" -O"$2/$3/$4"
rm "$2/$3/temp_original_copy.X.production.hex"
rm "$2/$3/temp_crc.X.production.hex"
```

But in the output I see some warnings:

```
User defined post-build step: [cd mcc_generated_files/boot && ./postBuild.sh /opt/microchip/xc16/v2.00/bin /home/mark/core dist/default/production core.production.hex false]
(1601) "+-CK=5000-AEFFF@5000w-4g5p814141AB" argument : checksum result destination (0x5000) overlaps with checksum range (warning)
(1601) "+-CK=5000-AEFFF@5002w-4g5p814141AB" argument : checksum result destination (0x5002) overlaps with checksum range (warning)
```

Since the bootloader does not work as expected (I get continue resets after downloading the application) I want to understand if it can be related to these warnings.

This macro is provided by the MCC itself.
I searched about this ([here](https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/Calculating-and-storing-checksum) for example) but I'm not able to understand what's happening.

Is there anything I have to change in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the warning.  It's saying that the checksum is being placed into the area of a checksum which is expected here.